# Another password prompt when waking from suspend

Tags: login-screen

After upgrade to ubuntu 15.04, I have to enter password for twice to unlock my system when it wakes up from suspend. The first password prompt looks weird, I've never seen it before and have no idea where it comes from:

[image]

I can enter my login password to get passed through it. Only after that the normal login prompt shows up.

What is this white password prompt? How can I disable it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this solution:

First:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
```

Then:

```
sudo killall gnome-screensaver
```

Suspend, resume and you will be direct on the Unity's password promt.

Comment: Looks like it works! Thank you for the answer. I have no idea what this `gnome-screensaver` thing is about.

Comment: Today, we can consider _gnome-screensaver_ as a legacy program that shows an animation on the screen after a time of inactivity or when the user locks the screen. Screensavers were created to prevent phosphor burn-in on CRT and plasma computer monitors when the same image were displayed for long periods. Nowadays, with LCD-LED technologies and warnings about energy efficiency, screensavers are going to fall into disuse.

Comment: Got same problem in 16.04 and the solution works also. Thanks!

Comment: This **does not** work on Lubuntu 16.04 where gnome-screensaver is **not** installed. For bug info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1296270

Comment: I am also same issue but `Package 'gnome-screensaver' is not installed, so not removed`. How do I resolve this ?

Comment: The answer is about Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity. In Lubuntu you could do `sudo apt-get remove light-locker`, reboot and check, but you'll loose the screen-lock function unless you want to apply [this workaround](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2014/03/26/using-xscreensaver-to-lock-the-screen-in-lubuntu/).